# AWS Glue DPU configurations

Tags: aws-glue

I see that the DPU is made of 4 vCPUs & 16 GB memory.  Is it possible to change this settings for vCPU, memory, so that I don't run out of DPUs or exceed the DPU limit.

I think there is a maximum limit of 5 DPUs for a Dev Endpoint, and a maximum of 2 DEV Endpoints for an account?

Regards

Yuva

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now there is no way to configure DPU memory, but you can request a [limit increase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) on your account to be able to use more DPUs.

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2019, there are two new types of workers:

> You can now specify a worker type for Apache Spark jobs in AWS Glue
>   for memory intensive workloads.
>
> Previously, all Apache Spark jobs in AWS Glue ran with a standard
>   configuration of 1 Data Processing Unit (DPU) per worker node and 2
>   Apache Spark executors per node. You can now pick from two new
>   configurations, G.1X and G.2X, that provide more memory per executor.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/04/aws-glue-now-supports-additional-configuration-options-for-memory-intensive-jobs/